# Python:- 'Book' object has no attribute 'add_format'

Tags: python

```py
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import easyxf, Formula,Workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy as xlwtCopy
#import*****************************

rb = open_workbook(InputWorkBook,formatting_info=True)
cell_format1 = rb.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_color': 'red'})
sh = rb.sheet_by_name(workSheet)
wb=xlwtCopy(rb)
ws=wb.get_sheet(0)
```

I have imported xlwt for python code.Getting below error for add format.
I want to add color to cell.Code is working before adding add_format

```py
ws.write(i,9,"abc",cell_format1)

cell_format1 = rb.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_color': 'red'})
```

```
AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'add_format'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import xlwt


book = xlwt.Workbook()

# add new colour to palette and set RGB colour value
xlwt.add_palette_colour("custom_colour", 0x21)
book.set_colour_RGB(0x21, 251, 10, 10)

# now you can use the colour in styles
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('Sheet 1')
style = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour custom_colour')
sheet1.write(0, 0, 'Some text', style)

book.save('test1.xls')
```